# Apply two different filters for image together with SVG

Tags: svg, svg-filters

In my project i have a set of predefined SVG filters, also i want
to provide for user configure some other filters, for example:

```html
<!-- predefined static filter(s) -->
<svg>
    <defs>
        <filter id="grayscaleFilter">
            <feColorMatrix result="grayscaleFilter" type="matrix"
                values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>

<!-- dynamically generated filter -->
<svg> 
    <defs>
        <filter id="compositeFilter">
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncR type="linear" slope="1.5" />
                <feFuncG type="linear" slope="1.5" />
                <feFuncB type="linear" slope="1.5" />
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="1.5" />
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncR type="linear" slope="1.5" intercept="1.5" />
                <feFuncG type="linear" slope="1.5" intercept="1.5" />
                <feFuncB type="linear" slope="1.5" intercept="1.5" />
            </feComponentTransfer>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg> 
    <image href="imagePath" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

**feMerge** - works only in context of one filter section

How can i apply both filters for image bellow

```
<svg> 
    <image href="imagePath" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the image in a `<g>` and apply one filter to the group anf the other to the image:

```
<g style="filter: url(#f1)">
    <image href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="filter: url(#f2)" />
</g>
```

An example:

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;">
    <defs>
        <filter id="f1">
            <feConvolveMatrix order="3" kernelMatrix="1   -1   1
             -1  -.1  -1
              1   -1   1" />
        </filter>

        <filter id="f2">
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0 0 1 0 0
       0 1 0 0 0
       1 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400"> 
  <g style="filter: url(#f1)">
    <image href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="filter: url(#f2)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Also depending on the filters you may try to to combine the filters in one filter like so:

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>


        <filter id="f">
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" 
                           values="0 0 1 0 0
                                   0 1 0 0 0
                                   1 0 0 0 0
                                   0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
          
           <feConvolveMatrix order="3" 
                             kernelMatrix="1   -1   1
                                          -1  -.1  -1
                                           1   -1   1" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400"> 

    <image href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="filter: url(#f)" />
 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write them both in the css filter property.

The rest of this example is taken from exaneta's answer.

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;">
    <defs>
        <filter id="f1">
            <feConvolveMatrix order="3" kernelMatrix="1   -1   1
             -1  -.1  -1
              1   -1   1" />
        </filter>

        <filter id="f2">
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0 0 1 0 0
       0 1 0 0 0
       1 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400"> 
    <image href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="filter: url(#f1) url(#f2)" />
</svg>
```

Note this does not yet appear to work in Chrome but it does work in Firefox.